# How filtered something from reflection?

Tags: java, android, reflection

// Initialized in JVM not by private constructor

// This field is filtered from reflection access, i.e. getDeclaredField

// will throw NoSuchFieldException

```
private final ClassLoader classLoader;
```

How something is filtered from reflection ? in android there is also white list and black list for reflection , How they filtered something from reflection?

Comment: Who is “they”? And why does it matter how “they” did something?

Comment: maybe I Write my question not clear , I want to know how hide a class from reflection ? I do not care who are they or ....

Comment: Indeed. When you want to know “How can I hide a class from Reflection”, you should ask exactly that. But the disappointing answer will be, you can not hide a class from Reflection. The JDK classes are developed together with the JVM. That’s a built-in feature, buried deep inside.

Comment: so what about the one mentioned  before  "This field is filtered from reflection access...

Comment: As said, this is a JDK class, developed by the same developers who developed the Reflection feature itself, also in coordination with the JVM developers. It doesn’t matter, how they do it, all that matters, is that you can’t copy the approach.

Comment: just answer I Do not know , your answer : 1.who are they 2 . It is not important 3.who care 4. it is fundamentally this way . you just need to say I do not know

Comment: @johnnyishere I guess Holger's comments are relevant (it's not just "I don't know").

Comment: @johnnyishere Could you provide a link to Android feature you mentioned (white list and black list for reflection)?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces

Comment: it say there are APIs that are non-sdk( that there is no api for programmer, they are internal) but we can use reflection to reach them . but between those non-sdk ,android will restrict programmer that even can not use reflection to reach them

Comment: I find there is a policy file and security manager ,  in java that make restriction for a program(code) . I do not know Android mechanism